# Cron script readiness check failed while updating the Module

Tags: magento2, cron, file-permissions

When I tried to `update my module`, Readiness check fails.

My `cron job` is already running.

```
Error from Updater Application Cron Script:

Found non-writable path(s):

generated/code/Magento/Cron
generated/code/Magento/Cron/Model
generated/code/Magento/Cron/Model/ScheduleFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ModuleFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/CronEventFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/Apm
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/Apm/DeploymentsFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/SystemFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/CountsFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ResourceModel
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ResourceModel/Counts
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ResourceModel/Counts/CollectionFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ResourceModel/Module
generated/code/Magento/NewRelicReporting/Model/ResourceModel/Module/CollectionFactory.php
generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor
generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/Interceptor.php
generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/CategoryTreeInterfaceFactory.php
```

But all my `folders` have `775` and `files` have `664 permission`.

Any Idea ?

Comment: This seems permission issue, your var/generation folder should have 777
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html